# Another linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given for $m \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, we write $A \geq B$ if $(A)_{i j} \geq(B)_{i j}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$. Analogous definitions apply to $A \leq B, A>B$ and $A<B$. For a sequence of $m \times n$ matrices, we write $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} B_{t}=B$ if $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(B_{t}\right)_{i j}=(B)_{i j}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.

I need to solve the following:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Show that if $(I-A)$ is invertible and $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}=O$ then
$$
(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}
$$
where, by definition, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$ is shorthand for $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{t} A^{k}$.

This is what I have done:

Given, $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

We need to show that if $(I-A)$ is invertible and $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}=0$ then
$(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$

Where, by definition, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$ is shorthand for $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{t} A^{k} .$

Since, by definition, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$ is shorthand for $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{t} A^{k}$.

given that if $(I-A)$ is invertible and $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}=0$ then
$(I-A) \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^{k}=I-A^{t}$

Take limit on both sides,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Rightarrow \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}(I-A) \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^{k}=\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(I-A^{t}\right) \\
\Rightarrow \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}(I-A) \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^{k}=I-\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t} \\
\Rightarrow(I-A) \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^{k}=I-\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}
\end{array}
$$

Further simplify the above expression,

We have, $(I-A) \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^{k}=I-\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}$

$\Rightarrow(I-A) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}=I-0 \quad\left[\right.$ Since $\left., \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} A^{t}=0\right]$

$\Rightarrow(I-A)^{-1}(I-A) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}=(I-A)^{-1} I$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}=(I-A)^{-1} \quad[$ Since $,(I-A)$ invertible $]$

Thus, $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$

Hence proved.

Would this be correct?

Comment: It looks fine...but I'd rather take out all the $\;lim\;$ notation and let only the infinite series. That way it'd be clearer and easier to check.

Comment: That's fair enough, thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is sound, but perhaps it can be made nicer and easier to see, by dropping all those annoying limits (we already know what is their definition!), and then I'd go:

$$(I-A)\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^{k+1}=A+\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k=I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(A^k-A^k\right)=I$$

...and we're done.

We can save the very last step as we know what the meaning of those infinite series are (kindda arithmetic of limits for matrices)

Comment: I think it is worth taking this argument back to finite sums, since your argument, as written, implicitly assumes that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k$ converges. Of course, underneath this, you're really just using a telescoping sum whose terms tend to $0$, but I think it's worth making this explicit.

Comment: That's really useful to know. Thank you :)

Comment: @TheoBendit Read the OP's post: in this case, that sereis notation is a way to denote the existence of a limit as defined there.